# Is it possible to create aliases for .Net classes?

Tags: powershell, alias, powershell-4.0

PowerShell 4.0

Is it possible to create the PowerShell alias for the .Net class? It doesn't work for me:

```
New-Alias -Force -Name someClass -Value [CompanyName.AppName.SomeNamespace.ClassName]
```

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847830.aspx):

> An alias is an alternate name or nickname for a cmdlet or for a command element, such as a function, script, file, or executable file. You can use the alias instead of the command name in any Windows PowerShell commands.

Classes are neither cmdlets nor functions/scripts/executables, so they can't be aliased.

What you can do is define [custom type accelerators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/simplify-your-script-by-creating-powershell-type-accelerators/), though:

```
[PSObject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators')::Add('mydate', 'System.DateTime')
```

(`[accelerators]::Add()` didn't work for me when I tested it)

Answer (score 3):

There's always the using statement:

```
using assembly System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
[MessageBox]::Show('Hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
(make sure System.Windows.Forms is loaded first)

```
$Accelerators=[PowerShell].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")
$Accelerators::add("myKey","System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys")
$Accelerators::add("myTB","System.Windows.Forms.TextBox")
```

Tested on PowerShell 3.0 Win7(x64) and 5.0 (Win10,x64), and you can try it on
4.0.